# How to keep selenium webdriver objects from becoming stale after leaving page?

Tags: python, selenium

I've run into an intractable problem trying to scrap an ajax filled site. After much struggle I've been able to automate my browser to download a single file off the site. Unfortunately, the task at hand requires me to leave the main page to get to the file. My problem is that after getting a list of the driver objects, once I leave the page it goes stale. I've tried to get around this by storing the index as an integer. Here is my code below:

```
while loop:
    open_folders()
    drFolder = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@data-rights='16777215']")
    drSurveys = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@data-rights='16711680']")
    inner_loop(create_list(drFolder, drSurveys), accum)
    accum += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around this by using the map function to update the list:

```
    while loop:
    open_folders()
    drSurveys = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@data-rights='16711680']")
    elecontainer = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@data-rights='16711680']")
    map(lambda: driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@data-rights='16711680']"), elecontainer)
    if elecontainer[accum].is_displayed():
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elecontainer[accum]).click(elecontainer[accum]).perform()
        if check_jquery():
            inner_loop()
    accum += 1
```

I did not have any experience with anonymous functions or the map function.
I later went back and updated it like so:

```
    while loop:

    open_folders()

    elecontainer = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[data-rights^='167']")

    map(lambda: driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[data-rights^='167']"), elecontainer)

    if elecontainer[accum].is_displayed():

        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elecontainer[accum]).click(elecontainer[accum]).perform()

        if check_jquery():

            urlstore = driver.current_url

            inner_loop()

    accum += 1
```